# How old is Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, age

How old is Wolverine? Wasn't he in the civil war or something? It seems like movies keep showing flashbacks of earlier and earlier events.

Comment: when i read this, so if he was in the civil war he could be 1000 years old? and i laugh. the civil war would make him around 175-200 years old. it was in 1861-5

Comment: Truly, the state of the American education system in full view.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is making a joke there. At least, I hope so. I mean, technically Wolverine IS somewhere between 50 and 1000 years old...

Comment: well he was in ww2 for sure. so he therefore cannot be 50, more like 80-1000 years old.

Comment: He's as old as his tongue, and a little older than his teeth. Wait... he's probably older than that, actually, since he's lost and regrown both several times.

Answer (score 22):

No one knows exactly for sure. In the comics story *Origin*, [James Howlett](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_(James_%22Logan%22_Howlett)) is born sometime between 1886 and 1897. There is no record of Wolverine fighting in the American Civil War in the Earth-616 universe.

In the movies, however, James Howlett was born earlier within the same century. *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* shows James and Victor fighting in multiple wars across time, including the American Civil War.

Comment: If only that montage had been the whole movie....

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: That montage and a few scenes of Liev Schreiber killing people and making sarcastic remarks = instant Oscar.

Comment: Wait. There's more movie after that? I've always just turned it off after it.

Comment: @phantom42: you're wiser than I am.

Comment: The wiki article you've linked says that "Wolverine's life began in Cold Lake, Alberta, Canada, sometime between 1882 and 1885, a couple of weeks before the 19th of April." The citation for the date is Origins #2. Something seems off.

Answer (score 3):

Wolverine was born in year 1886. The latest X-Men is set in the year 2023. This means Wolverine is right now 137 years old.

Comment: There is a storyline in *Wolverine & The X-Men* that flashes to 2042. The *Old Man Logan* story takes place over 50 years in the future.

Comment: But not in movie

Comment: What's your source for a birth year of 1886? Can you provide a quote, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

In the montage in the beginning it clearly shows him fighting red coats which means he at least fought in the american civil war if not the revolutionary war. So assuming he fought in the revolutionary war he's around 261 years old. If it was just the civil war he's  about 175 or so.

Comment: The question asks how old he is.  All you're doing is providing a lower bound on his age — you offer no evidence to rule out the possibility that he is 250, 500, or even 1000 years old.  Worse yet, you're providing *two different answers*, so we can know with mathematical certainty that at least one of them is wrong.

Comment: There are no red coats in the montage. The first battle is blue vs grey. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3lP3Sr0yKs

Answer (score 0):

There is a few comic lines that say 1832 also. So it's all about what you know by whether have or haven't read certain comments or have only watched the movies.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the SF&Fantasy Stack. Could you add _where_ it reads that, perhaps even a quote? That would make this a really good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the movies X-men origins begins in 1845 when wolverine is around the age of 10 so that would mean he would have been born close to 1835 so going from that year he would be around 181 in the year 2016